# (Windows) ncurses linking issues

Tags: c++, windows, include, ncurses

I'm really getting an headache here.
I'm trying to get ncurses running on my system, but the compiler returns this fatal error: "ncurses.h: no such file or directory".
Can anybody make some clarity inside of my head?
I swear I've been looking for an answer in the whole web for the last 2 hours, thank yall in advance <3

Here's what I did:

1. Installed following packages via MinGW Installation Manager (even though I didn't get the differences between these):

   - mingw32-ncurses (bin);
   - mingw32-libncurses (dev);
   - mingw32-libncurses (dll);
2. Made sure "C:\MinGW\bin" was included to my PATH environment variables (but I was already sure of that since I'm compiling with g++)
3. Included the path to "ncurses.h" file in my includepath in VSCode; I included "C:\MinGW\include\ncurses" for this specific case since that's there I found "ncurses.h" is EVEN IF there's also a "ncursesw" folder with the exact same headers (I don't know the difference)
4. I made sure to include -lncurses in my terminal when compiling (again, inside of /lib/ there are a couple files regarding ncurses (libncurses.a, libncurses.dll.a, libncurses.la and three copies named "libncursesw"), so once again I'm not sure what needs to be linked.

Just for clarity, here's my code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(){
    initscr();
    printw("Hello");
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

and here's my compiling command:
`g++ ncurses.cpp -lncurses -o test`

Comment: fyi - "_... fatal error: "ncurses.h: no such file or directory"..."_ is a compiler not a linker error.  It means that the compiler can't find the header file.  Have you added the directory containing the header file to the compiler include path ?  Also try `#include "ncurses.h"` as triangular brackets are usually used for system header files (specific differences would be another question).

Comment: The compiling command does not have any include paths.  Is that the commend you typed, or the generated command from a IDE?

Comment: @RichardCritten that's the command I typed, how exactly do I include the header file in my compiler include path?

Comment: Before doing anything particularly interesting, make sure `#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>` doesn't work.

Comment: @user4581301 oh ok, that actually works, but it's not clear to me why. What happens when I don't just include ncurses.h but also ncurses?

Comment: For your install the default system include folder is C:\MinGW\include. The preprocessor will look there for any <> includes. `#include <ncurses.h>` is going to look for C:\MinGW\include\ncurses.h. But ncurses.h sits inside the ncurses folder so `#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>` will look for C:\MinGW\include\ncurses\ncurses.h.

Comment: Is the `ncurses.h` file in `C:\MinGW\include` or is it in `C:\MinGW\include\ncurses`? With `#include <ncurses.h>` you tell it to look in `C:\MinGW\include`

Comment: Thank you all. @user4581301 got it, it's just a path then, but what's the point of adding the ncurses folder to the includePath then? It has nothing to do with the preprocessor?

Comment: I don't use it  so I'm not even close to an expert, but what I gather from questions here on Stack Overflow VS Code has three main config files. One of them tells the compiler what to do and if you've edited that one what you did should have worked. One of the other config files is for intellisense (the tool responsible for drawing most of the error squiggles and providing as-you-type diagnostics) and it also needs to know where the headers are. If you didn't get a big red squiggle under the include directive, you probably edited the intellisense file.

Comment: @user4581301 that absolutely makes sense. Thank you so much, once again!

Comment: Five bucks says ncursesw contains a wide characters version of ncurses so you can support more than just the oldie-and-moldy 8-bit character sets. Whether it's full-on modern unicode or the 16 bit version that existed when Microsoft standardized on it, I'd have to experiment. Or more likely read a bit of documentation. Yeah. I'd start with the docs.